# View internal std::vector data when debugging in XCode 4

Tags: debugging, xcode4, stdvector

On breakpoint XCode shows only aa array of vector members. So I can't view actual std::vector members, such as _M_impl. As I remember, there was this ability in XCode 3.x.

I need this data to set "Watch adress of ..." to check when it will be changed.

Comment: try `expr` in lldb console debugger interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can right-click in the xcode 4 variables window and select "Edit summary format...".  This provides you with the same functionality as xcode 3.

That said, I still have yet to figure out how to inspect STL containers in xcode.